# TextView.setText causes force close inside catch (but not otherwise)

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm trying to write a simple app to try out loading and playing sound files. I have two sounds, I want to get a list of them, then playback whichever is clicked. The following code works:

```
public class SoundPoolTest extends ListActivity {
    String sounds[] = { "shot", "explode" };
    SoundPool soundPool;
    int[] soundId = new int[sounds.length];
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < soundId.length; i++) {
            soundId[i] = -1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        soundPool = new SoundPool(20, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sounds));
        for (int i = 0; i < sounds.length; i++) {

            try {
                AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
                AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = assetManager.openFd("sound/"
                        + sounds[i] + ".wav");
                soundId[i] = soundPool.load(descriptor, 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                TextView textView = (TextView) super.getListView()
                        .getChildAt(i);
                textView.setText("Could not load file!");
            }
        }
    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(list, view, position, id);
        if (soundId[position] != -1) {
            soundPool.play(soundId[position], 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I mess up the argument of `assetManager.openFd` so that the files aren't found to test the exception handler, the application force closes before rendering the list (LogCat outputs `thread exiting with uncaught exception`). The problem is the `textView.setText("Could not load file!");` line; if I comment it out there's no problem. What's more puzzling is that if I leave `catch` empty and put the same piece of code into the `onListItemClick` method, so that it looks like this

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(list, view, position, id);
        TextView textView = (TextView) super.getListView().getChildAt(position);
        textView.setText("Clicked!");
        if (soundId[position] != -1) {
            soundPool.play(soundId[position], 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
        }
    }
```

it runs fine, changing the text when clicked as intended. I can't make sense of this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably `super.getListView().getChildAt(i);`
The `ListView`does not maintain all the child views created. It only keeps references to views that are on screen. Views that goes off screen are recycled and re-used for other content. This avoids having to manage hundreds of views if the underlying data is big.

Try loading the sound from the `getView()`method in the adapter instead. In general, avoid trying to get a hold on a `ListView` item from outside `getView()`.

Comment: Do you mean just calling `super.getListAdapter.getView()` or something more elaborate? If former, I can't make sense of the official documentation; it just gives the syntax `public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`, I don't know what I'm supposed to give it as the `convertView` parameter.

Comment: You don't have to call getViez(). getView() is called by the system for each item of the list. Therefore, your try/catch block should be in getView()

Answer (score 0):

In your for() loop make this changes and then try.

```
for (int i = 0; i < sounds.length; i++) {

        try {
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = assetManager.openFd("sound/"
                    + sounds[i] + ".wav");
            TextView textView = (TextView) super.getListView()
                    .getChildAt(i);
            soundId[i] = soundPool.load(descriptor, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            textView.setText("Could not load file!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This way the variable `textView` is not even alive outside the `try` block.

Comment: Try to declare textView as a global.